# ClojureScript + React-Native - Embed Videos

Tags: react-native, clojurescript, react-native-video, cljsrn, re-natal

I am new to ClojureScript. I would like to embed video (Youtube) to the hybrid mobile app using ClojureScript and React Native. I have tried to implement **react-native-video** and **react-native-youtube** plugins in ClojureScript for achieving this. But, both of these end with a crash. I don't know whether there is something wrong with referring to the library or not.

Using **react-native-video**:

```
(def Video (js/require "react-native-video"))
(def video-view (r/adapt-react-class Video))
```

The component reference is:

```
[video-view {:style {:position "absolute"
                            :top 0
                            :bottom 0
                            :left 0
                            :right 0}
                      :source {:uri "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M8Fn8SfXw3M"}}]
```

Using **react-native-youtube**:

```
(def YouTube (js/require "react-native-youtube"))
(def video-view (r/adapt-react-class YouTube))
```

The component reference:

```
[video-view {:style {:flex 1
                              :margin-bottom 60
                              :padding-top 10
                              :padding-bottom 10}
                      :video-id "M8Fn8SfXw3M"
                      :play true
                      :fullscreen true
                      :loop true}]
```

Neither of these two options is working.

Below is the crash report:

```
> Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for
> built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components)
> but got: object This error is located at:
>      in RCTView
>      in RCTView
>      in RCTScrollView
>      in ScrollView
>      in t
>      in RCTView
>      in :page-art-single
>      in RCTView
>      in .a
>      in RCTView
>      in :main
>      in py
>      in RCTView
>      in RCTView
>      in t  Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite
> components) but got: object.    This error is located at:
>      in RCTView
>      in RCTView
>      in RCTScrollView
>      in ScrollView
>      in t
>      in RCTView
>      in :page-art-single
>      in RCTView
>      in .a
>      in RCTView
>      in :main
>      in py
>      in RCTView
>      in RCTView
>      in t  undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.map.setNativeProps') D/ReactNative(15325):
> ReactInstanceManager.detachViewFromInstance()
```

I am using **lein** for compiling ClojureScript  **Re-Natal** for building this ClojureScript-based React Native app.

Is there anything wrong with the above code? Anyone, please help?

Reference:

[react-native-video](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-video)

[react-native-youtube](https://github.com/inProgress-team/react-native-youtube)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could embed YouTube video by using ReactNative WebView.

```
(def ReactNative (js/require "react-native"))
(def web-view (r/adapt-react-class (oget ReactNative "WebView")))
```

The component reference:

```
[web-view { :style {
                            :width 400
                            :height 200
                            :zIndex 10}
                      :javaScriptEnabled true
                      :domStorageEnabled true
                      :source {:uri "https://www.youtube.com/embed/M8Fn8SfXw3M"}}]
```

I think react-native-video is not supporting youtube videos.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what error you're getting and which setup you have, try calling the modules like this instead:

```
(def Video (aget (js/require "react-native-video") "default"))
```

Comment: I updated the crash report and the utility I have used for building the project.
I tried below method.

(def Video (js/require "react-native-video"))
(def video-view (r/adapt-react-class (oget Video "default")))


This time it didn't crash and I can successfully go to the page in which the video-view component added. But, I can't see the video component rendered in the view.

Comment: What do you get if you print Video to the console? `(js/console.log Video)`

Comment: It has printed the video component object. But, I can't see the component in the view. @vikeri